# I'm trying to use the new Qiskit Dynamics module. Do I have to do anything special to import it?

Tags: qiskit

I'm running in the IBM Quantum Lab environment, so I should have access to all the latest code. But I get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit_dynamics'

Answer (score 1):

The next line in jupyter book works fine for me:

```
!pip install qiskit-dynamics
```